# Rails + Paypal. How to pay different sellers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, rubygems, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have a rails app where my users can login through Paypal (Oauth2).

I would like to give the ability to my logged users (buyers) to make payments to other (multiple) paypal accounts (sellers).

My understanding is that I can achieve that only via adaptive payments (classic API).

1) Is my assumption right?

2) Is the best gem for adaptive payment this one: paypal-sdk-adaptivepayments?

3) Should I create a classic app as opposed to a REST API app?

4) If 3 is true, should I also handle the login using the classic app? (as of now I m using a REST API app for login)

5) Can the user pay without having to insert again his credentials?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using https://github.com/jpablobr/active_paypal_adaptive_payment  for chained, split payments.

You need to create a classic app and provide `:appid => "APP-80W284485P519543T"`,

for test `:appid => "APP-80W284485P519543T"`.